# Bootstrap 4 fixed bottom navbar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My current navbar is:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="">page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How do I make it so that, even if there is not enough content to "push" it down, it is still at the bottom? `navbar-fixed-bottom` does not work because it overlaps with content if it reaches the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what "fixed" does, it goes in front of the other elements not below them. Just put a couple of blank lines at the bottom of your page, or better, add a CSS `padding-bottom` to your page container.

Here is an example, adjust the padding value to what you want:

```css
.page-container {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="">page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="page-container">
  <p>first line</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>last line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

** **I tried Like this as below , it worked for me**

```
 <div class="fixed-bottom">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).